# Hide android ToolBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am developing a tabbed application and for some tabs I want to hide the toolbar. I am setting the visibility as gone to accomplish that. Below is my XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                                 >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/offwhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I am seeing some item still on the top section of the screen. please check the screen shot. Am i doing it correctly? Is there any better way to hide Toolbar.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your manifest file?

Comment: the padding is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the toolbar programmatically using the following code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
```

And if that doesn't fix the problem, try removing from your AppBarLayout,

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
```

and change your toolbar to this

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
```

This would fix your problems

Answer (score 0):

To hide the toolbar in your App, just add two lines in your style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    ...

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```